# Are ferrofluidic seals used in spaceflight? Main applications? Human-rated?

Tags: spacesuits, space-station, engineering, human-rating, capsule

Comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39479/12102) have inspired this quesiton.

Wikipedia's [Ferrofluidic seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrofluidic_seal) sez:

> Ferrofluid-sealed feedthroughs routinely operate in environments including [ultra-high vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high_vacuum) (below 10⁻⁸  mbar), temperatures over 1,000 °C, tens of thousands of RPM, and multiple-atmosphere pressures.

Are ferrofluidic seals used in spaceflight? If so:

1. What are the main applications
2. Are they used in human-rated applications, i.e. to seal an atmosphere being breathed by humans against loss to space?

Comment: I know of none in shuttle, but difficult to prove a negative.

Comment: @OrganicMarble seems like all [patents and scholarly articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=ferrofluid+seal+discovery&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) post-date 1983. Seeing as shuttle was planned before 1981 and first launched in April 1981, I doubt that it would've been included in the design that late. Don't know how much the design evolved beyond STS-1 though.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn excellent point!

Comment: I'm extremely interested in this @uhoh if this isn't answered I'll make my first bounty in 2 days.

Comment: The necessary permanet magnetic materials might be too heavy for spaceflight.